# How to get the progress of the materialized view creation in PG

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have a `create materialized view` running for days now, is there a way to know the progress of the query?

Any metric would be OK, e.g. percentage finished, time left, disk space to be consumed by the left work. I'm mainly concerned about the disk space usage, which I can get a rough estimate from other metrics such as percentage finished.

PG version is 12.2